# Adding a new line to existing txt file in c++

Tags: c++

As a tutorial I've been a question to add new line to an existing file with a list of items. i've tried numerous ways to add it. no luck yet

```
            ofstream outdata;
            ifstream indata;

            indata.open("fruits.txt");
            outdata.open("fruits.txt");
            
            if(indata.is_open()){
             std::string fruit;
             std::cout << "enter a fruit to list "<<endl;       
             std::cin >> fruit;
             outdata << "\n" << fruit << "\n" << endl;
            
             indata.close();
             outdata.close(); 
             
            return 0;
            
            }
```

This part of the code is supposed to ask the user to enter a value. Its supposed to be stored as new line without deleting the existing line. But here I'm. I've seen a few answers here. but can't find anything understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open a file for writing its contents are immediately removed, if the file already exists.

```
       outdata.open("fruits.txt");
```

You opened the same file for writing here. This is before your code tries to read anything from the same file (I don't actually see anything in your code that tries to read it, I presume you left that part out). And by the time you get to the file it's already empty and there's nothing to read any more from it.

You have three choices:

1. Read the entire contents of the file into your program, and only ***then*** open it for writing and write out the new contents.
2. Open a different file for writing. After finishing reading and writing both files, and closing them, rename the new file to the original file.
3. Open the file for appending:

   ```
    outdata.open("fruits.txt", std::ios::app);
   ```

It's not necessary to open it for reading, this will add to the end of the file, instead of overwriting it.

Comment: the third option worked, i actually did that too, maybe the arrangement of the code was messed up somewhere,